# Custom names for resources in cluster created using HEAT templates in Openstack

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron, openstack-horizon, openstack-heat

I am trying to create a cluster using Heat Templates of Openstack. I have following template defining my resource group.

```
cluster:
    type: OS::Heat::ResourceGroup
    properties:
        count: { get_param: instance_count }
        resource_def:
            type: ../templates/vm.yaml
            properties:
                image: { get_param: image }
                flavor: { get_param: flavor }
                private_network : { get_attr : [network, name] }
```

This works, but the name of all these servers is very cryptic. I was wondering if it would be possible to provide a prefix to name to each of the instances.

Or another way could be is I can `str_replace` a template value with the current index of the cluster count.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, got it from the [ResourceGroup documentation](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/heat/template_guide/openstack.html#OS::Heat::ResourceGroup). Use `%index%`.

Here is the example from the documentation.

```
resources:
  my_indexed_group:
    type: OS::Heat::ResourceGroup
    properties:
      count: 3
      resource_def:
        type: OS::Nova::Server
        properties:
          # create a unique name for each server
          # using its index in the group
          name: my_server_%index%
          image: CentOS 6.5
          flavor: 4GB Performance
```